# Display managed path in search results

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, enterprise-search

I'm trying to display the managed path a site is on in my search results.

To be more clear: I have setup a core results webpart which fires a custom query to retrieve all site collections within a certain search scope. These are in a webapplication which has a couple of managed paths (wildcard) setup, which somewhat classify the site (apps, teams, etc.). To enhance the search results webpart, I'd like to show this 'category' to the user.

I have the URL property / variable available in XSLT, but that contains the entire site URL. That means I'll have to parse that and get the sitename. With C# or a regex I'd be able to, but in XSLT it seems not that straightforward.

Or I could add a column to the search results which holds the managed path, but I'm unsure wether that column is at all available. Is there a good reference which colums can be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The managed path is not exposed in a Managed Property or Crawled Property.

I would go down the xslt route - thats the approach that should work everywhere.

Comment: That's the only solution I found. I don't really like those kind of solutions completely depending on how a string is formatted, but there's no real choice here I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have a Managed Property called "SiteTitle" that you can use to get the site's name.
You need to add this Managed Property to Search Core results web part by adding the name `<column name="SiteTitle"/>` to the "fetched Properties" xml located in the editor part configurations under
"Display Properties". After adding the Managed Property you can use in your xsl.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No it doesn't, please read before you post. You're not answering the question.